# How to config routeProvider and locationProvider in angularJS?

Tags: angularjs

I want to active html5Mode in angularJS, but I don't know why it's not working. Is there anything wrong with my code?

```js
angular
    .module('myApp',[])
    .config(function($locationProvider, $routeProvider) {
        $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
        $routeProvider.when('/', {
           templateUrl: 'partials/home.html', 
           controller: HomeCtrl
        });

        $routeProvider.when('/tags/:tagId', {
            templateUrl: 'partials/result.html', 
            controller: TagResultCtrl
        });
        //$routeProvider.otherwise({redirectTo: '/home', controller: HomeCtrl});
     });
```

in html

```html
  <a href="tags/{{tag.id}}"><img data-ng-src="{{tag.imageUrl}}"></a>
```

Answer (score 63, accepted):

The only issue I see are relative links and templates not being properly loaded because of this.

[from the docs regarding HTML5 mode](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/$location)

> #### Relative links
>
> Be sure to check all relative links, images, scripts etc. You must either specify the url base in the head of your main html file (`<base href="/my-base">`) or you must use absolute urls (starting with `/`) everywhere because relative urls will be resolved to absolute urls using the initial absolute url of the document, which is often different from the root of the application.

In your case you can add a forward slash `/` in `href` attributes (`$location.path` does this *automatically*) and also to `templateUrl` when configuring routes. This avoids routes like `example.com/tags/another` and makes sure templates load properly.

Here's an example that works:

```
<div>
    <a href="/">Home</a> | 
    <a href="/another">another</a> | 
    <a href="/tags/1">tags/1</a>
</div>
<div ng-view></div>
```

And

```
app.config(function($locationProvider, $routeProvider) {
  $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
  $routeProvider
    .when('/', {
      templateUrl: '/partials/template1.html', 
      controller: 'ctrl1'
    })
    .when('/tags/:tagId', {
      templateUrl: '/partials/template2.html', 
      controller:  'ctrl2'
    })
    .when('/another', {
      templateUrl: '/partials/template1.html', 
      controller:  'ctrl1'
    })
    .otherwise({ redirectTo: '/' });
});
```

If using Chrome you will need to run this from a server.

Comment: It isn't really explained here, but when using HTML5 mode, your browser will actually request the full URL (including the state) from the server any time the user directly enters the URL, navigates to the URL from another server, or hits refresh. Since your AngularJS app is likely a single-page application, this means the server will return a 404 Not Found error because it only knows about index.html.

To fix this, you must set up your server to return your index.html for all 404 errors, then handle unexpected states in your route provider (i.e .otherwise({ redirectTo: '/404-not-found' }) )

Comment: hot to fix when reaload pagge gives 404 :s

Answer (score 5):

Following is how one can configure $locationProvider using `requireBase=false` flag to avoid setting base href `<head><base href="/"></head>`:

```
var app = angular.module("hwapp", ['ngRoute']);

app.config(function($locationProvider){
    $locationProvider.html5Mode({
        enabled: true,
        requireBase: false
    }) 
});
```

Comment: This works great to solve my problem. However, I am using search parameters in my url, and when I add this code I no longer am able to refresh the page. Do you know why this could be?

Answer (score 4):

AngularJS provides a simple and concise way to associate routes with controllers and templates using a `$routeProvider` object. While recently updating an application to the latest release (1.2 RC1 at the current time) I realized that `$routeProvider` isn’t available in the standard angular.js script any longer.

After reading through the change log I realized that routing is now a separate module (a great move I think) as well as animation and a few others. As a result, standard module definitions and config code like the following won’t work any longer if you’re moving to the 1.2 (or future) release:

```
var app = angular.module('customersApp', []);

app.config(function ($routeProvider) {

    $routeProvider.when('/', {
        controller: 'customersController',
        templateUrl: '/app/views/customers.html'
    });

});
```

**How do you fix it?**

Simply add angular-route.js in addition to angular.js to your page
(grab a version of angular-route.js here – keep in mind it’s currently
 a release candidate version which will be updated) and change the
module definition to look like the following:

```
var app = angular.module('customersApp', ['ngRoute']);
```

If you’re using animations you’ll need angular-animation.js and also need to reference the appropriate module:

```
 var app = angular.module('customersApp', ['ngRoute', 'ngAnimate']);
```

Your Code can be as follows:

```
    var app = angular.module('app', ['ngRoute']);   

    app.config(function($routeProvider) {

    $routeProvider
        .when('/controllerone', {
                controller: 'friendDetails',
                templateUrl: 'controller3.html'

            }, {
                controller: 'friendsName',
                templateUrl: 'controller3.html'

            }

    )
        .when('/controllerTwo', {
            controller: 'simpleControoller',
            templateUrl: 'views.html'
        })
        .when('/controllerThree', {
            controller: 'simpleControoller',
            templateUrl: 'view2.html'
        })
        .otherwise({
            redirectTo: '/'
        });

});
```

Comment: Do we need to run this on a server, and if we do, which one please?

Comment: @surendra I added some explanation to your good answer. hope it is ok with you.

Answer (score 3):

**Try this**

If you are deploying your app into the root context (e.g. https://myapp.com/), set the base URL to /:

```
<head>
  <base href="/">
  ...
</head>
```

[Angular Documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$location/nobase)

Comment: This is indeed something that has been fixed in the current releases of angular;  You may want to make sure it's understood the version of angular this answer applies to, since this question was originally posted and answered in 2012, and this answer wouldn't have been appropriate for the angular version available then.

Answer (score 0):

you could try:

```
<a href="#/controllerone">Controller One</a>||
<a href="#/controllerTwo">Controller Two</a>||
<a href="#/controllerThree">Controller Three</a>

<div>
    <div ng-view=""></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

@Simple-Solution

I use a simple Python HTTP server.  When in the directory of the Angular app in question (using a MBP with Mavericks 10.9 and Python 2.x) I simply run

`python -m SimpleHTTPServer 8080`

And that sets up the simple server on port 8080 letting you visit `localhost:8080` on your browser to view the app in development.

Hope that helped!