# Angular JS Uncaught Error: [$injector:nomod]

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have the following app in index.js:

```
angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute', 'ngAnimate']);

    .config(function($urlRouterProvider, $locationProvider, $routeProvider) {

        $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');
        $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
    });
```

And I have 2 routes **/about** and **/contact**, each route has his own file with controller (contact.controller.js) and contact.js where I configure the route like:

```
angular.module('myApp')

    .config(['$routeProvider',

        function($routeProvider) {

            $routeProvider.when('/about', {
                templateUrl: 'assets/javascript/about/about.html',
                controller: 'AboutCtrl',
                controllerAs: 'vm'
            });
        }
    ]);
```

My issue is if I do like this I recive this error

> Uncaught Error:
>   [$injector:nomod] http

But works I remove .config() from index.js.

What I'm doing wrong, can someone explain me how can I keep both configs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To use `$urlRouterProvider` you need ui-router, but you are using angular router instead. Try like this:

```
$routeProvider.otherwise({ redirectTo: '/' });
```

I personally prefer [ui-router](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router)

Comment: now works, but if I go to /blog for example, even if I have route created its 404\

Comment: @Hiero see this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13832529/how-to-config-routeprovider-and-locationprovider-in-angularjs)

Answer (score 1):

You **should** Not have two configs in index.js
what you can do is to append the code in single .config , So your code now becomes

```
angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute', 'ngAnimate']);
.config(function($urlRouterProvider, $locationProvider, $routeProvider) {


// Rest of configurations.



function($routeProvider) {

        $routeProvider.when('/about', {
            templateUrl: 'assets/javascript/about/about.html',
            controller: 'AboutCtrl',
            controllerAs: 'vm'
        });
    }
]);
```

what i had in one of my projects was a long config function , so for the configurations and routes i have a single file index.js