# AngularJS - locationProvider not working / base tag stops angular working

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to add relative url's to my single-page angular app without the hashes by using locationProvider to enable html5, but I'm having issues with the base tag.

When I add it like this:

```
<base href="/" />
```

the site comes up unstyled.

-

When I change it to this:

```
<base href="./" />
```

the styles load, but all angular code stops working, so the views don't appear, and clicking on links does nothing.

-

My file structure is like this:

```
'dashboard' folder
    app.js
    index.html
    'pages' folder
        home.html
        page2.html
        etc...
    'js' folder
        angular.js
    'css' folder
        style.css
```

-

app.config code:

```
app.config(function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
$routeProvider    
    .when('/', {
        templateUrl: 'pages/home.html',
        controller: 'mainController as main'
    })

    .when('/home', {
        templateUrl: 'pages/home.html',
        controller: 'mainController as main'
    })

    .when('/newPayroll', {
        templateUrl: 'pages/page2.html',
        controller: 'page2Controller as page2'
    })

    .when('/employeesList', {
        templateUrl: 'pages/page3.html',
        controller: 'page3Controller as page3'
    })
$locationProvider.hashPrefix('');
$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
})
```

-

href links are like this:

```
<a href="/home">
```

Comment: When I add it like this:

<base href="/" />
the site comes up unstyled.

-

When I change it to this:

<base href="/" />. I can't find any difference

Comment: Edited. Should've been a dot before the forward slash

Comment: I think it has something to do with your relative paths . Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13832529/how-to-config-routeprovider-and-locationprovider-in-angularjs